# How can I make my custom webkit scrollbar transparent?

Tags: css, webkit, scrollbar

I've designed a custom webkit scrollbar in transparent png format but it is not transparent on my site.

Is there any way I can make the the left edges transparent?

Here is my code:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 15px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: transparent url(images/backgrounds/scrollbar.png) repeat-y;
}


::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
}
```

The website url is: http://captainjackspiratepartys.co.uk/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using Chrome and your bar didn't work for me, I had to use:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece:start{
     background: transparent url(images/backgrounds/scrollbar.png) repeat-y !important;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece:end{
    background: transparent url(images/backgrounds/scrollbar.png) repeat-y !important;
}
```

also, I don't believe you can actually make the bar transparent with just css. Instead of transparent, try to make your image have just a dark background. It will be less obvious than white

Comment: hmm I use chrome too and the bar is visible? Okay thanks for the advice

Comment: oh I know why it wasn't working for you - I haven't added in the thumb yet!

Comment: the real thumb I'll be putting in - the one at the moment is just temporary

Answer (score 5):

A transparent scrollbar track isn't possible to the Body element but I've noticed that it is possible to Div elements. What you can do is to create a wrapper Div and place your contents there instead of placing the contents directly into the body section.

sample:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    /*no code needed here*/
}
div#wrapper{
    overflow:auto;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
}
body{
    overflow:hidden;
}
```